# unable to change image for facebook sharing

Tags: php, html, facebook

I am using facebook sharing through facebook sharer , everything is working fine except the image share, by default it is taking the logo image but i want different image.

here is the code which I am using

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $fb_url; ?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)"> <span><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> </a>
```

Any kind of suggestion would be highly appreciated, Thanks for reply in advance in comment box.

Comment: And what did you already tried ?

Comment: Set an `og:image` tag.

Comment: Yes I already set the og:image in the meta description tag but the image does not change on the fb sharer page